# Is a formatting directive expected in variadic functions?

Tags: go, formatting, variadic-functions

I have a variadic function `respond` that takes several positional arguments and an `any` slice spread at the end. Depending on the context, the function uses the last parameter in different ways (note how `message` and `data` differ depending on the value of `status`.):

```golang
func respond(w http.ResponseWriter, status int, format string, a ...any) {
    var (
        statusOk bool
        message  string
        data     interface{}
    )
    if status >= 300 {
        statusOk = false
        message = fmt.Sprintf(format, a...)
        data = nil
        log.Error().Msg(message)
    } else {
        statusOk = true
        message = format
        data = a[0]
        log.Info().Msg(fmt.Sprintf("%d", status))
    }
    // issue response
    responder := render.New()
    responder.JSON(w, status, map[string]interface{}{
        "statusOk": statusOk,
        "status":   status,
        "message":  message,
        "data":     data,
    })
}
```

For the call below I do not get any warnings:

```golang
respond(w, http.StatusNotFound, "person %v does not exist", personId)
```

For the next one, however, the warning `respond call has arguments but no formatting directives` is raised (but the code runs as expected,  `person` is a `struct`):

```golang
respond(w, http.StatusAccepted, "updated", person)
```

To my amateur eye, **it looks like the variadic function expects to have a formatting string and parameters for this format at the end**. But why would that be the case? Is there a limitation to what a variadic function is supposed to do?

Or should I better split `responder` in two, one for each case ("ok" and "not ok")?

---

Also see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26486 and https://go.dev/src/cmd/vet/testdata/print/print.go (line 316) for a discussion of that message in Go's code (what I have is a warning from a linter, as @mkopriva and @JimB mentioned in their comments)

Comment: This is not a language / compiler error. This warning is from a linter of which the default setting is informed by convention. Either ignore it or change the linter settings.

Comment: @mkopriva: yes, I realize this and wanted to understand the reason for that warning. Do you mean that it is conventional (but not compulsory) to only use varidic functions for formatting?

Comment: @JimB. Thank you. Interstingly enough this message also exists in the Go code (https://go.dev/src/cmd/vet/testdata/print/print.go, line 316)

Comment: @WoJ, yes `go vet` will report these when present in std library function calls. The calls with formatting strings are all known there, so arguments passed is can always be analyzed.

Comment: @WoJ you could emulate the stdlib by declaring another function called `respondf` which would do the Sprintf call and pass the result to the original `respond` function, and then update the original `respond` to not use Sprintf anymore. e.g. https://go.dev/play/p/abab2V7juGt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning comes from the linter because you're calling the `respond()` function with a format string not matching the arguments provided after that.

This specific message comes from the [printf Analyzer](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/analysis/passes/printf) which documents that:

> printf: check consistency of Printf format strings and arguments
>
> The check applies to calls of the formatting functions such as fmt.Printf and fmt.Sprintf, **as well as any detected wrappers of those functions**.

Since your `response()` function uses the `format` and `a` parameters to call `fmt.Sprintf()` as-is, this is considered as a wrapper for `fmt.Sprintf()`.

If you want to avoid / get rid of this warning message, the easiest "fix" is to not use those parameters as-is, e.g. make a copy of one of the arguments, and pass that:

```
// Make and use a copy to avoid being marked as a wrapper of fmt.Sprintf
format := format
message = fmt.Sprintf(format, a...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your `format` parameter is being used in `Sprintf` and, in the second case, the `updated` string doesn't have any format directives iex: `%v`.

```golang
respond(w, http.StatusAccepted, "updated", person)
```

You should probably refactor your function.

Consider this approach:

*Note: You don't need to set `statusOk = false` and `data = nil` that are the default value for that types.*

```golang
func respond(w http.ResponseWriter, status int, message string, a ...any) {
    var (
        statusOk bool
        message  string
        data     interface{}
    )

    if status >= 300 {
        log.Error().Msg(message)
    } else {
        statusOk = true
        data = a[0]
        log.Info().Msg(fmt.Sprintf("%d", status))
    }

    // issue response
    responder := render.New()
    responder.JSON(w, status, map[string]interface{}{
        "statusOk": statusOk,
        "status":   status,
        "message":  message,
        "data":     data,
    })
}

func example() {

    message := fmt.Sprintf("person %v does not exist", personId)
    respond(w, http.StatusNotFound, message, personId)

    message = "updated"
    respond(w, http.StatusAccepted, message, person)
}
```